# Click on button first time show alert, click second time execute code

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I want to show users, when they click on a button for the first time, an alert when in a date field a value is chosen which lies before the current date. When they insist to this choice for good reasons, I want them to give a second chance to click on the same button, and then the value has to be submitted.

The click event is defined in a function:

```
$("#edit_date_btn").click(function(){
 // do something and save
}
```

In an other function the comparing is handled. The basic code is:

```
function edit_date_compare() {
....
if(usersDate < today)
 { //show alert
  return false; // needed for the first click so the input is not submitted
 }
```

I've tried several options e.g. with a count on the click function (on a second click 'return true;' instead of 'return false;') but it seems difficult to handle this situation. Any ideas how to make this successful? It could be with Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried to use a flag? Like keeping it false by default and on the click of button, do your compare operation if the flag is false. And after compare operation, set the flag to true if it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea with the `count on the click function`. I suspect you might have difficulty implementing it. You need a separate variable that tracks the number of clicks. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwmquxaL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clickCount = 0;

  $("#btnSave").click(function () {
    if (clickCount > 0) {
      AlertSave();
    } else {
        AlertFirst();
      clickCount++;
    }
  });
});

function AlertSave() {
  alert("Some code has been executed!");
}

function AlertFirst() {
  alert("Are you sure you want to perform this operation?");
}
```

Comment: Thx. I was on the right track. After looking better to the implementation and your answer my issue is solved. Additionally I've added also a variable unset, in case a user acts more then once in the same way immediately after the first action.